# ORACLE avg,max,min salary TRIGGER

Tags: oracle

so i'm trying to create a trigger, but always have an error that says

> Trigger LOG_SALARY compiled
>
> LINE/COL  ERROR
> --------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 2/2       PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored 3/9       PL/SQL: ORA-00934: group
> function is not allowed here Errors: check compiler log
>
> Error(2,2):PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
> Error(3,9):PL/SQL:ORA-00934:group function is not allowed here

this is my code

```
'''alter table department add AVG_SALARY number(10);
alter table department add MAX_SALARY number(10);
alter table department add MIN_SALARY number(10);

insert into department (AVG_SALARY, MAX_SALARY, MIN_SALARY) values (AVG(salary), MAX(salary) ,MIN(salary));

create or replace TRIGGER log_salary 
 after update of salary on employee
 for each row
begin 
 insert into DEPARTMENT(AVG_SALARY, MAX_SALARY, MIN_SALARY)
 values(AVG(SALARY),MAX(SALARY),MIN(SALARY));
end;

update department
set salary = salary + 100.0
where SSN =888665555;

select * from DEPARTMENT;'''
```

could you tell me what is wrong with my code?
thankyou in advance!

Comment: What you are trying to do is an astoundingly bad idea that violates a core principle of RDBMS systems.  You should almost _never_ store a value that can be calculated when needed.  Thus, @Gordon Linoff's suggestion "that you just use a view to calculate the values on-the-fly."

Answer (score 0):

You are *inserting* new rows into the department table.  I think you want to update them.  The logic looks like this:

```
create or replace TRIGGER log_salary 
 after update of salary on employee
 for each row
begin 
    update department 
        set (AVG_SALARY, MAX_SALARY, MIN_SALARY) = 
             (select AVG(SALARY), MAX(SALARY), MIN(SALARY)
              from employee
              where e.department_id = :new.department_id
end;
```

This however will probably generate a mutating table error.  Addressing that is really difficult.  For instance, consider this:

```
emp_id   dept_id    salary
   1       1         10
   2       1         10
   3       1          5
```

If you change `emp_id`'s salary to 20, then the max is 20.  But if you change the salary to 5, then the max remains 10.

I would suggest that you just use a view to calculate the values on-the-fly.